# Devise: How to render registration/new form onto sessions/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hi am trying to render my devise `registration/new` form onto my `sessions/new` page. I want the user to be able to either create or login on the same page.

Here is what I have so far, but it's not working. It thinks it's a login form and not a creation form, as it lets me login on my registration form.

In `app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb`, I have this code:

```
<br>
<br>

<body class="bg-dark">
    <div class="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="container text-white">
                    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                    <h1>Sign in</h1>
                    <p>Welcome back.</p>
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
                                <%= f.input :email,
                                            required: false,
                                            autofocus: true,
                                            input_html: { autocomplete: "email"} %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-8 ">
                                <%= f.input :password,
                                            required: false,
                                            input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" } %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-8 ">
                                <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", class: "btn btn-info" %>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class=" text-white ">
                    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(:user)) do |f| %>

                    <h1>Create an account</h1>
                    <p>Its quick and easy.</p>
                    <%= f.error_notification %>

                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
                                <%= f.input :email,
                                            required: true,
                                            autofocus: true,
                                            input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-8 ">
                                <%= f.input :password,
                                            required: true,
                                            hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                                            input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-8 ">
                                <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
                                            required: true,
                                            input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <%= f.button :submit, "Create Account", class: "btn btn-success" %>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<div class="container">
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Comment: What's `resource`? Could it be current user, if you are already logged in?

Comment: Hey @ SwiftHub, I just re-created the same scenario, and it was working just fine. The only thing I forgot to do, is to re-start the server after running ```rails generate simple_form:install```. Can you tell us if some error is raised and if so, can you show us?

Comment: Hey thanks will try this when I get home later. I’m not entirely sure what resource is, but it’s required